# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero lanzar mi servidor SQL. Sin embargo, al intentarlo, me dice que `No se pudo establecer datadir`.

```
C:\Users\antoi>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"
2019-04-12T07:13:41.936191Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 5504
2019-04-12T07:13:42.292515Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\DESKTOP-A0M91CP.lower-test
2019-04-12T07:13:42.292766Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\DESKTOP-A0M91CP.lower-test
2019-04-12T07:13:42.300874Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2019-04-12T07:13:42.342684Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-04-12T07:13:42.435514Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

He leído [aquí](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1652459/bases-donnees/mysql/installation/erreur-lancement-mysql/) que el problema podría ser que tengo un `MySQL Server 8.0` en el directorio`C: \ Archivos de programa` y que debería estar en `C: \`. Sin embargo, no sé cómo cambiar esto en la medida en que el instalador de MySQL no parece darnos la opción.

Cuando intento lanzar MySQL

```
C:\Users\antoi>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql" status
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Aquí están los servicios de estado:

[image]

Utilizo Windows 10

Comment: bajaste el servidor, desde el asistente de [MySQL installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) y como lo instalaste, por que yo tengo windows 10, lo baje del enlace que te paso. lo tengo en una ruta similar a la tuya y funciona sin problemas

Comment: @anonimo Si, es lo cual utilicé. Voy a desinstalar y lo reinstalar el servidor MySQL Server 8.0.15.

Comment: una vez que lo reinstales, simplemente añadelo a tus variables de sistema y trata de hacer desde el CMD  de windows, `mysql -u root -p` luego pones tu contraseña así y dependiendo del resultado nos comentas